# Automapping doesn't have an Id mapped

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

```
My Entity Class:
public class Building 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// internal Id 
        /// </summary>
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
..............
}
```

My Mapping:

```
var model = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Building>()
                        .Setup(s => s.FindIdentity = p => p.Name == "Id")
                        .Where(t => t.Namespace == "SpikeAutoMappings");

var database = Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(DatabaseConfigurer)
                        .Mappings(m=>m.AutoMappings.Add(model));
```

I need somebody to help me see what is wrong because I keep having this error when run unit test:

```
Initialization method TestProject1.MappingTestBase.TestInitialize threw exception. FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException:  FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

 --->  FluentNHibernate.Visitors.ValidationException: The entity doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id)..
```

Answer (score 9):

both answers above are right; unless you specify differently, the automapper assumes that you have an int Id field.
If your Id is long, the automapper might not recognize it correctly.
try defining a MappingOverride for your class(es), like so:

```
public class UserMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<User>
{
    #region IAutoMappingOverride<User> Members

    public void Override(AutoMapping<User> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(u => u.Name);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

the Id() function allows you to override the automapper's convention of what the ID field should be.
for further info on overriding, see http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Overrides.
Cheers,
Jhonny

Answer (score 2):

Generally, using `AutoMapping` is a poor policy because the filed `Id` must exist in your database tables. Instead, consider using a fluent mapping generator, such as [NMG](http://nmg.codeplex.com/releases/view/58079) to handle your mapping.

In this case, you would first want to download/install the application, then generate the Mapping Files from your database (Oracle, SQL and various others).

In order to create the Mapping Files, first create an `/Entities/` folder within your project. Next, configure the generator software as follows:

**Preferences**

1. Generated Property Name = Same as database column name (No change)
2. Mapping Style = Fluent Mapping
3. Field or Property = Auto Property

**Languages available: C# and VB**

1. Folder : `[your project folder]\Entities`
2. Namespace : `[your project namespace].Entities`
3. Assembly Name: `[your project name].Entities`

Next, either Generate All or Generate the Specific Table.

All of the `*.cs` and `*Map.cs` files should now be created in your project (you can add them with `Add Existing Item...` if they don't show up).

Using Fluent, you will see something like the following:

```
Id(x => x.keyName_ID)
  .Column(x => x.keyname_ID)
  .GeneratedBy
  .Sequence("keyname_ID")
```

or

```
Id(x => x.keyName_ID)
  .Column(x => x.keyname_ID)
  .GeneratedBy
  .Identity()
  .Column("keyname_ID")
```

or

```
Id(x => x.keyName_ID)
  .Column(x => x.keyname_ID)
  .GeneratedBy
  .Assigned()
```

So, now we need to specify the `Id` using `FluentMapping` with `Fluent nHibernate`. To do this, you need to overwrite the `Id` line of on code in each of the `Map` files in the solution. Simply add:

```
Id(x => x.KeyName_ID)
  .GeneratedBy
  .GetGeneratorMapping()
  .IsSpecified("KeyName_ID");
```

Where `keyname_id` is the column name of the `id` in your database, rather than the one created.

Notice that in your mapping at the `BuildSession` you must have:

```
(...).Mappings(m => 
    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<[one of your entities]>()
);
```

And, now `Id` is mapped. :) I hope this helps!

Comment: You make my day! 3 days I spent trying to find what is wrong in my mapping. All examples, all solutions from stackoverflow didn't work. Finaly I changed `m => m.AutoMappings` to `m => m.FluentMappings` and... a miracle happened. Everything works!

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Automapping is that as long as your Entity class has the line:

```
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
```

the automapper will treat it as an ID with no further help from the programmer (i.e. no need for the FindIdenity code you are using in your AutoMap call).

The only difference I see in your ID declaration is that you use a type long instead of int.  Don't know if this matters or not.

Comment: Thx Tom. Am using Oracle 10g and Id is long type. 
Tried your line and took out the setup FindIdentity... still got the same error....